# How to add BitmapEffect to the text of a styled button

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, contentpresenter

I'd like to make the text within a button glow when it becomes KeyboardFocused.

I am unable to do this. Here is my xaml:

```
 <Style x:Key="BorderlessSymbolButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MetroButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="White" Opacity="0" GlowSize="3" Noise=".1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>

                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      x:Name="Content"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                      BitmapEffect="{TemplateBinding BitmapEffect}" >

                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GlenairMediumBlue}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>-->
                        <!--<Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource BorderDropShadow}"/>-->
                        <Setter Property="BitmapEffect"  >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="White" Opacity=".4" GlowSize="3" Noise=".1"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MouseOverBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GlenairLighterOpaqueBlueSolidColorBrush}" />

                    </Trigger>-->
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledBorderBrush}" TargetName="Border"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks very much! Was unable to find the solution to my issue on google/SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used your exact template because I wasn't able to just copy/paste it into Visual Studio without changing resource names ect. When posting code to fix try and make it completely isolated, makes fixing problems much easier for us :D

The template I've provided below applies a drop shadow effect to the content of a button when the keyboard focus is set, I used Effect instead of BitMapEffect because it's much faster and also BitMapEffect is now obsolete. You might need to tweak the effect parameters to make it glow better.

[image]

```
 <Window x:Class="GlowingButton.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Background="WhiteSmoke"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter TargetName="test" Property="Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DropShadowEffect Color="Blue" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger.Setters>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Margin="100" Content="test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks kindly for the solution and tip on BitMapEffect. Also, My apologies for posting so many of my own Resource references. Will try to be more aware next time. Cheers :)